# Is there a naming convention for "linq" methods?

Tags: c#, linq, naming-conventions

Is there any naming convention for "utility" methods whose only reason of existence is to make your Linq statements clearer?

Example:

```
List<Member> myList = GetMembers();
myList.Where(AllMembersAreBlue);

//lots of code...

public bool AllMembersAreBlue(Member member)
{
    //code
}
```

What would be the most correct way to name methods like the mentioned above (**AllMembersAreBlue**) ? Is there any convention?

I did some googling and found no answers.

Comment: Well i'd say a convention is usually not to do that, i can think of a few very rare use cases but typically something looking at a linq query is expecting all of the code to be visible right here. If you really want to do this however i'd go with an extension method such that you'd replace q.Where(AllMembersAreBlue) with q.BlueMembers()

Answer (score 1):

As long as you understand the intent I'd say use whatever name suits you.

In this case I don't really see the point of a separate method, though:

```
myList.Where(m => m.Members.All(x => x.Color == Color.Blue))
```

Comment: I oversimplified the example, but it won't always be like that. I just wanted to know if there was a common convention for that. Doesn't seem like there is, though.